# Heroku redirecting to http page

Tags: php, heroku

I just made a new heroku application and I have a homepage with a form in the middle which when submitted redirects to the search results page with a GET request. The homepage has the https scheme but when I submit the form it redirects to the http scheme on the search results page.

I can manually change the url in the address bar to change it from http to https and it works but I can't just tell users to change the url in the address bar.

Comment: What domain service do you use? I mean, what's the nameserver for your domain

Comment: @DreamBold godaddy

Comment: Somebody has downvoted my answer and I have deleted it for now. You should set redirection as I mentioned. So your domain nameserver is Heroku at the moment, right?

Comment: What's your domain name? I can have a look for the nameserver

Comment: "when I submit the form it redirects to the http scheme"—what is [the `action` attribute  on your form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attributes_for_form_submission) set to? If you're telling the browser to submit it to `http://...`, that's what it's going to do.

Comment: @Chris its just the relative path to the search file, in my case i put ./search

Answer (score 0):

You can add directives to the `.htaccess` file at the root of your project to do this. Put this rule at the top of the file, if the file does not exist, create a new `.htaccess` file and add it.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Or you can try with these

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```